# Assignment in do-while/while doesn't work as expected

Tags: php, while-loop, do-while

I want to assign a random value between 48 and 122 to `$num` except for the value 79.

So to slove this I tried a do-while and a while loop to solve the problem. I tested it, but it doesn't work as expected and it ends in an endless loop.

```
while($num != 79){
    $num =  rand(48, 122);
};
```

or:

```
do {
    $num = rand(48, 122);
} while ($num != 79);
```

So why doesn't this work as I want it to? Can anyone tell me where my mistake is?

$num shout be a number between 48 and 122 but NOT 79.

Comment: You want it to be an endless loop or ? Can you explain more.

Comment: Your logic is wrong. You want to assign a new random number as long as the number is equals to 79, because otherwise you have your random number except 79 and you can leave the while loop

Comment: I wont a number, but NOT 79.

Comment: Can you come up with more explanation? @hamburger

Answer (score 4, accepted):

declare `$num` with value 79 to make sure loop starts
and the loop will quit when `$num!=79`

```
$num = 79; // to make sure the loop will iterate at least once
while( $num==79 ){ 
    $num =  rand(48, 122);
}
```

as per your request, excluding 111 too, modify the condition as below:

```
while( $num==79 || $num==111)
```

do-while will use the same condition, and no need to assign 79 as initial value, as the do-while will run at least once.

```
$num = 0; //just to declare the variable
do {
    $num = rand(48, 122);
} while ($num == 79); // you can use || here too: while ($num == 79 || $num == 111)
```

Comment: THX, but thats not the soloution. what if the ($num =  rand(48, 122)) gives 79 back?

Comment: the loop will keep working, that's the goal of a loop, to keep working until a certain condition is fulfilled

Comment: assuming `rand(48, 122);` will never generate any number except 79 (which looks quit not possible) the loop will iterate for ever, but this is a true miracle -if happen- :)

Comment: Whenever 79 will be assigned to $num the loop will run again and when $num is assigned to any different number only then it will exit loop.

Comment: Whats the solution if I do not wont 79 and 111

Comment: you have to use **or** `||` in the while-loop condition

Answer (score 6):

In both cases the logic is wrong, you're repeating the loop while your number **is not** 79

You should repeat the loop if the number **is** 79:

```
$num = 79;// assign value to avoid Notice error 
while($num == 79){ 
    $num =  rand(48, 122);
};
```

or:

```
do {
    $num = rand(48, 122);
} while ($num == 79);
```

Answer (score -2):

try this code

```
$num = 0;
while(true){
   $num = rand(48,122);
   if( $num != 79){
      break;
   }
}
```

Comment: You should not use code snippets for PHP code, it's only useful with HTML code.

Comment: You can just write `while($num == 79){` like in the accepted answer, the `if` is not needed.

Comment: well that's a correct answer ... and i thought he tried it and didn't work, that's why.